# Open url in browser and force page reload

Tags: android, browser, android-intent

I use the following code to open an URL in browser:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

But if the page behind the url was already opened in browser, running the above code doesn't refresh the page. How could I force page refreshing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to my knowledge you cannot force it to refresh from the Android side (unless you're showing it in your own WebView) You'd have to set the page itself to auto refresh, that would presumably ensure whatever is being shown is likely to be up to date.

Answer (score 7):

Looking for an answer as well... this seems to work for me:

```
Uri url = Uri.parse(website+"?time="+(new Date().getTime()));
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(url);
activity.startActivity(i);
```

because the new get parameter forces a reload.